# problem when doing php memcache calls inside a loop

Tags: memcached

I have the following code :

```
foreach( ... ) 
{
  $m = new Memcache;
  $m->connect('10.1.1.243', 11211);
  $key = ... // calculate key
  $data = $m->get($key);
  if($data) return $data;
  $data = ... // else fetch data from sql
  $m->set($key, $data, 3600);
  return $data;
}
```

The loop goes approximately 100 times. And the $m->get($key) statement seems always to be missing to get the data from memcache.

Any ideas? Thanks.

btw: I was using persistent connections to the memcache servers. Don't know if it's relavent. I actually tried to move the new Memcache and connect() part outside, but I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

- You are doing `return` in a `foreach` - thus, you are not looping at all,
- Obviously, check that `$key` is the same - try setting it to the same value always just for test,
- You say you fetch your `$data` from sql, but if you are doing any manipulations, check `if($data)` is testing for something (i.e. that $data is defined and not false),
- Per http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php, you should use `set` like this:

  $m->set($key, $data, 0, 3600);

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop is useless, since you use 'return' which exits the function and breaks the loop.

btw: do not call 'new Memcache' and 'connect()' more than once.